# How to pass AWS Gateway parameter to AWS lambda function in Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I deployed REST API into AWS lambda function. I am trying to use API Gateway GET method with lambda function to get a single value from MySQL database. I want to pass *id* in the URL. Here is my handler function

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type User struct{
Id int `json:"id"`
Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Ids struct{
Id int `json:"id"`
}

//func handler(id Ids) (*User, error)
//id1 := id.Id
func handler( id events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (*User, error) {
    id1 := id.Body


user := &User{
        Id: id1,
        Name : "abc"
    }
    return user, nil
}

func main(){
lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

I am getting result while I create test event in lambda function with the test for handler(events.APIGatewayProxyRequest)

```
{
"body":123
}
```

or for handler(id Ids)

```
{
"id":123
}
```

When I use API Gateway to create GET method for the above lambda function, I am getting "internal server error" as it is giving null value to read database. I use the URL https://xxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com/test/user/123, but it is not reading the value of *id*. What am I doing wrong here? Should I need to pass the JSON for the handler function? If yes, how to pass JSON in the URL? or is there any other method where I can pass the value to handler?

Comment: Have you used proxy integration of Api gateway with lambda?

Comment: Yes, I have used proxy integration method, but still getting "internal server error". Working fine with test event in lambda function, but getting error when I use API gateway.

Comment: APi gateway will pass an event with structure that is different than what you tested it with. The best way to check it, is simply to print out the event object provided by api gateway to your lambda and inspect its structure in CloudWatch Logs. Then you will know how to get your data.

Comment: @Marcin I tried to print out event object and i found that it is printing 0 for whatever the value I pass in the URL. When I pass _xxx/user/123_, it prints 0. Am I doing anything wrong in passing the value through URL?

Comment: Example event you should be getting is shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html).

Comment: @Marcin, I tried, but same error. May be I am doing wrong in the handler function. I am using handler function `func handler(id events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (*User, error)` and `id1=id.Body` and i also used `id1 = id.Path`. But not getting the value which I am passing. Is it  because I am not using `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse` as output? I have found that I need to use `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse` if I want to use proxy integration. Is there any other way by which I can pass value in URL without using `events.APIGatewayProxyRequest`?

Comment: I'm not too familiar how `go` works in lambda. So can't help much with the specific question about go.